# Print Array in PHP with specific name

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I want to print an array as a table in front page but I don't want to show the last name. How can I write code to do this in PHP?

```
?php
// Array representing a possible record set returned from a database
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);
```

Please help

Comment: You are not expecting the other SO users to write the actual code for you, aren't you? Please show us what you tried so far and what difficulties you faced on your way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<table>    
<?php
 foreach ($records as $key => $value) {   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$value['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value['first_name']."</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";

 }    
?>
</table>
```

This will show **id** and **first_name** in table format.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>    
<?php
 foreach ($records as $value) {   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$value['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value['first_name']."</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";

 }    
?>
</table>
```